# How to generate HTML table for test execution summary in Email (Outlook) body

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

**Background**: 
In our project[selenium-cucumber-java-Mvn based] we have test execution reporting done through- master thoughts Cucumber report (mvn dependency). This Report get generated in the test>target directory and we are sharing this folders Link embed in an email to everyone automatically for reporting. Here recipient has to open this link to see the status. Link looks like- 
http://localhost:63342/Automation/TestExecutionReports/02-08-2018/Run-1/cucumber-html-reports/overview-features.html

**Question**: 
Now we have a need to send Execution summary also in the email so that one can see high level status without even drilling through Link. 
So we need to insert a Tabular format- with columns -TC Name, Status, Execution Time, Overall Count etc. in email body itself in addition to the above Link.
Can someone plz help me doing this?

**Other info**: 
I don't know much how internally master though works, but it gathers the execution data via a JSON file. And we are generating this report in the onExecutionfinish method of TestNGExecutionListener.
our current report looks like an attached snap.
Our json is contains the following info-

```
[
  {
    "line": 1,
    "elements": [
      {
        "before": [
          {
            "result": {
              "duration": 3849355155,
              "status": "passed"
            },
            "match": {
              "location": "CucumberHooks.InitBrowser()"
            }
          }
        ],
        "line": 3,
        "name": "Add Account and verify details",
        "description": "",
        "id": "add-account-and-verify-details;add-account-and-verify-details",
        "after": [
          {
            "result": {
              "duration": 129904,
              "status": "passed"
            },
            "match": {
              "location": "CucumberHooks.TearDownTest(Scenario)"
            }
          }
        ],
        "type": "scenario",
        "keyword": "Scenario",
        "steps": [
          {
            "result": {
              "duration": 13810592966,
              "status": "passed"
            },
            "line": 5,
            "name": "I have Logged in to Grid application",
            "match": {
              "location": "leaseSearchSteps.i_have_Logged_in_to_Grid_application()"
            },
            "keyword": "Given "
          },
          {
            "result": {
              "duration": 4659413417,
              "status": "passed"
            },
            "line": 6,
            "name": "I select Accounts and Contacts option from the Homepage",
            "match": {
              "location": "createAccountSteps.selectAccountsAndContactsOptionFromTheHomepage()"
            },
            "keyword": "And "
          },
          {
            "result": {
              "duration": 3470670155,
              "status": "passed"
            },
            "line": 7,
            "name": "Click on Add Account button",
            "match": {
              "location": "createAccountSteps.clickOnAddAccountButton()"
            },
            "keyword": "Then "
          },
          {
            "result": {
              "duration": 28732919407,
              "status": "passed"
            },
            "line": 8,
            "name": "Create Account with Account name as \"Pacific UAT Test Account\"",
            "match": {
              "arguments": [
                {
                  "val": "Pacific UAT Test Account",
                  "offset": 37
                }
              ],
              "location": "createAccountSteps.createAccountWithAccountName(String)"
            },
            "keyword": "Then "
          },
          {
            "result": {
              "duration": 2243415294,
              "status": "passed"
            },
            "line": 9,
            "name": "Click on View button",
            "match": {
              "location": "createAccountSteps.clickOnViewButton()"
            },
            "keyword": "Then "
          },
          {
            "result": {
              "duration": 121318771,
              "status": "passed"
            },
            "line": 10,
            "name": "Verify the newly created Account name",
            "match": {
              "location": "createAccountSteps.verifyTheNewlyCreatedAccountName()"
            },
            "keyword": "Then "
          }
        ],
        "tags": [
          {
            "line": 2,
            "name": "@Test"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "name": "Add Account and verify details",
    "description": "",
    "id": "add-account-and-verify-details",
    "keyword": "Feature",
    "uri": "src/test/resources/cucumber/featureFiles/AU/addAccountAndVerify.feature"
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your [mcve] where you attempted to send results via email and any error messages, etc.

Comment: @Jeffc: I never said that there is a problem in the emailing part, I want to know how can I generate a HTML table for the Summary and include in email body..

Comment: `we have a need to send Execution summary(Tabular format- for TC Name, Status, Execution Time, Overall status)in email body itself with the Link. Someone plz help me with it.`... that sounds exactly like what you are asking. If that's not what you are asking, you need to rewrite your question to make it clear.

Comment: @ JeffC: Okay, tried making in more clear, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont have code but I think a probable approach can be like below- 
First write some code to generate Table Template with its Header, Main Table, Rows and Columns and Footer. 
Then insert the Data into this table by reading it from the features.html page you have (as mentioned in url ). You should be able to read data for pass, fail or whatever needed from this html web page through standard methods [like- getText()] of Selenium . 
In the end get this whole table appended to a StringBuilder and send in email message as bu using setting content of thmlSourceEmbed as text/html..hope this help

Comment: Thanks for explaining, it helps..I'll try it out.. :)